# Output in one number

Tags: bash, gnu

Hello I have a task to count the number of symbolic links (not regular files nor directories etc.) in directory
/bin having b as the first letter of their names.

```
>  find /bin -name "b*" -type l  -printf l  > list.txt
```

But it outputs

> 1111

What should I do to change the output to one number (I mean 4) insted of these four 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To count correctly also symbolic links with line breaks:

```
find /bin -name "b*" -type l -printf "l" | wc -c >list.txt
```

Comment: I think it should be `-printf %l` no?

Comment: @Jetchisel: `l` can be any character.  One character is output for each link found.

Comment: Where does the `-printf` option come from? I don't find it in https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/find.html

Comment: @Fravadona: I assume she/he uses GNU `find`.

Comment: Ah, no wonder I didn't find that option in the `find` man of macOS. Shouldn't you correct it with a `-exec printf '1%.0s' {} +` ?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to count the links in a Bash script by storing the output of `find` in an array and counting the array entries:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Singular|Plural format string
__links_count_format=('There is %d link\n' 'There are %d links\n')

# Capture the links found by the find command into the links array
mapfile -d '' links < <(find /bin -name "b*" -type l -print0)

# Get the links count
links_count="${#links[@]}"

# Print the number of entries/links captured in the array
# shellcheck disable=SC2059 # dynamic format string
printf "${__links_count_format[links_count>1]}" "$links_count"

# Print the links captured in the array
printf '%s\n' "${links[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

`-type l` will find all the symbolic links and print a 1 for each. Then use `wc` to count characters

```
find /bin -name "b*" -type l -printf 1|wc -c > list.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below `awk` based implementation as well

```
controlplane ~ ➜   find /bin -type l | awk -F'/' '$3 ~ /^f/ {count++}END{print count}'
5

controlplane ~ ➜   find /bin -type l | awk -F'/' '$3 ~ /^b/ {count++}END{print count}'
2

controlplane ~ ➜
```